# Black opaque view when clicking on screen in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I am working on a site and came up with an issue when using it in Internet Explorer 9

> `http://www.tarpaflex.com/acatalog/black-silver-super-heavy-duty-tarps.html`

If you click anywhere on the screen in IE9 the screen goes black almost.

Any ideas would be appreciated

[image: opaque example of blackout]

Comment: I've been noticing this myself on several sites the last few days.  I suggested migrating this to the WebApps stack site, as this seems to be a site-side compatibility issue with IE9 and not a problem with your computer, maybe they'll have som ebetter info. :)  It seems to be because of old(er) implementations of Lightbox.  Hitting the 'broken page' button in IE 'fixes' it as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a java error on the page regarding image loading. I suspect IE9 is handling that error differently than other browser.  When you put the page in Compatability mode, it appears to work fine.

\\Greg